# Add spacing between rows in Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a Listbox which has a ItemSource binding to a property in the code behind.

```
<Border BorderBrush="#d6786a" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="15" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <ListBox x:Name="ListSrc" Background="#ececec" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListBoxData}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="4" Margin="15"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
</Border>
```

As you can see from the picture below the items are directly above/below one another. How am I able to add some padding between the rows?

[image]

Comment: You need to add a margin or a padding in your ItemTemplate.

Comment: @TimBourguignon What would I add inside the `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`Tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add something like this to your `ListBox`

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```